# How do I group my pandas columns to map and create a new column based on map values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a data frame of students id along with number of tests they have taken for each subject. I have to group it according to IDs with subjects and number of tests as map.

What I have:

```
Id     Subject     Number_of_Tests
101    Maths       6
101    Science     8
101    History     10
102    History     5
102    Maths       4
102    Science     7
```

What I want:

```
Id     Tests                                  Grade
101    {Maths:6, Science:8, History:10}     A
102    {History:5, Maths:5, Science:7}      B
```

Also, after grouping like this, I want to add one more column to this called "Grade", which is based on the newly created "Tests" Map Field.
For example, if the number of tests in Maths is greater dhan 5 and if the number of tests in Science is greater than 5 and if the number of tests in History is greater than 5, then grade "A", else "B".

Could anyone please help me on this.

Comment: Your expected output is confusing, is it list of list or you want list of dict?

Comment: @Sociopath I basically want it as a map, like in scala. And also want to refer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
# create a list of both columns on groupby
new_df = df.groupby('Id', as_index=False).aggregate({"Subject": lambda x: x.to_list(), "Number_Of_Tests": lambda x: x.to_list()})

# create a new column `Grade` based on condition
new_df["Grade"] = ["A" if all(j>5 for j in i) else "B" for i in new_df["Number_Of_Tests"]]

# create a column Tests using other 2 columns 
new_df["Tests"] = [{k:v for k,v in zip(i,j)} for i,j in zip(new_df["Subject"], new_df["Number_Of_Tests"])]

# drop unwanted columns
new_df.drop(["Subject","Number_Of_Tests"], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
   Id    Grade     Tests
0  101     A     {'Maths': 6, 'Science': 8, 'History': 10}
1  102     B     {'History': 5, 'Maths': 4, 'Science': 7}
```

**Edit**:

```
mask1 = (df["Subject"] == "Maths") & (df["Number_Of_Tests"] > 3)
mask2 = (df["Subject"] == "Science") & (df["Number_Of_Tests"] > 5)
mask3 = (df["Subject"] == "History") & (df["Number_Of_Tests"] > 7)

df["Grades"] = np.select([mask1, mask2, mask3], ["A", "A", "A"], "B")


def func(x):
    if "B" in x.values:
        return "B"
    return "A"


new_df = df.groupby('Id', as_index=False).aggregate({"Subject": lambda x: x.to_list(),
                                                     "Number_Of_Tests": lambda x: x.to_list(),
                                                     "Grades": func})

new_df["Tests"] = [{k:v for k,v in zip(i,j)} for i,j in zip(new_df["Subject"], new_df["Number_Of_Tests"])]

new_df.drop(["Subject","Number_Of_Tests"], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Hi @Sociopath, thanks for the answer. But could you please let me know how to access from the dict ("Tests" Column) instead of accessing from the List ("Number_Of_Tests" Column)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. What you're trying yo access here?  The entire `dict ` or  marks of particular subject?

Comment: The Grade should be based on multiple conditions on the dict. For example, instead of taking 5 as threshold for all subjects, if it's different for different subjects like maths >3, science >5 and history >7, then grade "A" else "B".

Answer (score 0):

You originally asked your question with the output for `Tests` being a list. This is the code that would provide that output. I will try to create another version for dict later:

1. The `Tests` column is pretty straight forward. First, join the relevant columns into a sting. Later, in the `.groupby()`, you will aggregate these values as a list.
2. Create the `Grade` column by getting the `.min()` of each group and returning `A` or `B`. Later, you can merge this back into the new consolidated dataframe.

---

```
df['Tests'] = df['Subject'] + ': ' + df['Number_of_Tests'].astype(str)
df['Grade'] = (df.groupby(['Id'])['Number_of_Tests'].transform('min') > 5).replace([True,False], ['A','B'])
df = pd.merge(df.groupby(['Id'])['Tests'].agg(list).reset_index(),
              df[['Grade','Id']], on='Id').drop_duplicates(subset='Id')
df
Out[1]: 
    Id                                Tests Grade
0  101  [Maths: 6, Science: 8, History: 10]     A
3  102   [History: 5, Maths: 4, Science: 7]     B
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the structure of your dataframe so that it will be easier for manipulation than to a format that is not easily manipulatable like dict.

```
df = df.set_index(['Id', 'Subject']).unstack()

        Number_of_Tests              
Subject         History Maths Science
Id                                   
101                  10     6       8
102                   5     4       7
```

Now Just add a column based on the required condition.

```
df['Grade'] = np.where((df['Number_of_Tests'] > 5).all(axis=1), 'A', 'B')
```

Output

```
        Number_of_Tests               Grade
Subject         History Maths Science      
Id                                         
101                  10     6       8     A
102                   5     4       7     B
```

#### OR

If you want the `dict` anyways,

```
df['Tests'] = df.groupby('Id').apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x.Subject, x.Number_of_Tests)))
```